# How to solve the one dimensional wave equation with $u(x,t)=F(x-t)+G(x+t)$

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

consider the partial differential equation $u_{tt}=u_{xx}$

with boundary condition $u_x(0,t)=u_t(0,t)$

and initial conditions $u(x,0)=f(x)$ and $u_t(x,0)=0$

How to solve this with the method of characteristics, that is with knowledge that $u(x,t)=F(x-t)+G(x+t)$ is a solution to $u_{tt}=u_{xx}$ ?
I know how to solve this with homogeneous boundary condition like dirichlet or neumann, but not with this type. 
With D'Alembert we find the following condition $u_t(0,t)=f'(x)/2+f'(-x)/2$. How to continue?

Comment: Do you know d'Alembert's formula? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_formula.

Comment: I do but then you're still not done because you have to adjust that to the boundary condition aswell

Comment: Which would give you an ODE for $u$. Try writing everything in the post and let's see if and where you get stuck.

Comment: @eranreches Oke one sec.

Comment: @eranreches did it:)

Comment: You forgot a minus in the first term. What about $u_{x}\left(0,t\right)$? Can you equate the two? Notice - your previous version with the $t$ dependence was better.

Comment: Once you apply the initial conditions you get $$u(x,t) = \frac{1}{2} \bigg[ f(x-t) + f(x+t) \bigg]$$ Applying the condition $u_{x}(0,t) = u_{t}(0,t)$ yields $$f'(-t) + f'(t) = -f'(-t) + f'(t) \implies 2f'(-t) = 0 \implies f'(-t) = 0$$ Can you now determine $f$?

Comment: What do you mean by the "  ' "  cause in one case you differentiate with respect to x in and in the other with respect to t?